# MVC API not hitting controller

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm moving some of internal projects from NET Core 2.0 to 3.0, and having trouble with getting the controller to execute after middleware has finished. Honestly I'm a bit frustrated as a similar approach used to work with NET Core 2.0.

I've uploaded my test project to GitHub:
https://github.com/wonea/MVC-API-Routing-Test

The test project details three middleware stages; SecurityMiddleware, UserValidatorMiddleware, WebSocketMiddleware. So upon booting the API you can set breakpoints on each of the individual stages and they will be hit in the correct order. However upon passing the HTTPContext on the final middleware stage it returns but does not hit the controller.

In Startup.cs I configure my services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(_configuration);

    // memory cache
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

    // CORS
    var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();

    services.AddCors(builder =>
    {
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin();
        corsBuilder.WithOrigins("*");
        corsBuilder.AllowCredentials();
    });
}
```

I've detailed the request pipeline, setting up WebSockets, performing the middleware, and then triggeringmy controller as an endpoint.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
{
    appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
    appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);
    appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnStopped);

    Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        appLifetime.StopApplication();
        // Don't terminate the process immediately, wait for the Main thread to exit gracefully.
        eventArgs.Cancel = true;
    };

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseSecurityMiddleware();
    app.UseUserValidation();

    // websockets
    var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions
    {
        KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)
    };
    app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
    app.UseWebSocketMiddleware();

    // put last so header configs like CORS or Cookies etc can fire
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

I'm only ever going to need one controller, so don't need any fancy config.

Comment: Did you also make changes to the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method in `Startup.cs`?  In the that method you have `services.AddMvc`.  You could try `services.AddControllers()` in Core 3.0.  And you have `options.EnableEndpointRouting = false` even though you have (rightly) configured Endpoint Routing in the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)` in your question

Comment: @Winthorpe Thanks, I've revised my question but the controller is still not being resolved.

Comment: sorry I could not be of more help.  I cloned your repo and I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: @Winthorpe With the help of an answer I've figured it out. Please see the updated code.

Answer (score 3):

I see your controller is setup like

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MainController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
```

Note the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) say

> Replace [controller] with the name of the controller, which by convention is the controller class name minus the "Controller" suffix.

For example, I have a "Work" controller that looks like

```
[Route("api/Work")]
[ApiController]
public class WorkController : ControllerBase
{
```

(it also has the `ApiController` attribute).

This would then be accessed at httpx://localhost/api/Work

You can then specify other endpoints on the api with the parameter to the `HttpGet` or `HttpPost` attribute.

```
[HttpGet("Test")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Test()
{
```

Would be httpx://localhost/api/Work/Test

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction. I've added an answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, my routing was at fault.

My launch settings were point directly to the controllers location

[image: launchSettings.json]

Then my controller was duplicating the routing. So the main controller was being resolved on.

localhost:51234/api/main/api/main

[image]

I've flattened the main controller's routing now

[image: New Main Controller]